# Why does an image saved from the bounding box produced from a model have much lesser resolution compared to the original image

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have trained the faster_rcnn_resnet50 model using the the Tensorflow object detection api. I have trained the model for images of size (1366,768)  and am using the same size while testing. However, when I save the content of the bounding box as a separate image, I observe that the image dimension gets reduced to (250,50) which is a quite significant drop. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Predicted image: [(1366,768) dimension image from test set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMNex.jpg)
Bounding box saved as image [image dimension becomes (250,50)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LIwZ.jpg)

I am adding the following lines of code below the last cell `object_detection_tutorial.ipynb`to save the region inside the bounding box as a new image

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
box = np.squeeze(boxes)
for i in range(len(boxes)):
    ymin = (int(box[i,0]*height))
    xmin = (int(box[i,1]*width))
    ymax = (int(box[i,2]*height))
    xmax = (int(box[i,3]*width))
    roi = img[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax].copy()
    cv2.imwrite('path/engine_box_{}.jpg'.format(str(count)), roi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bounding box is an area containing the object detected by the model, of course, its size would be much smaller than that of the original image. What is your expectation?